# How to delete a sentence after the pound sign (#) in a sentence in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to delete a sentence that is after a hash found in a sentence. This process should happen on all lines that have pound signs, for example:

**abcde#efg hijk**

**aaaabbbcc**

**ghij#kloa.bcd**

It will look like this

**abcde#**

**aaaabbbcc**

**ghij#**

I made the code below with `re.findall`, but when it finds an empty space, it does not delete the rest, look:

```
text = 'abcde#efg hijk \n\n ghij#kloa.bcd'    
result=re.findall(r'#(\w+.\w+\s+)', text)  
>>['efg hijk \n\n ']
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: should the output of `'abcde#efg hijk \n\n ghij#kloa.bcd'` be `'abcde#\n\n ghij#'`?

Comment: try `result=re.findall(r'#.*', text)` then calling `replace` on your text for all the elements of `result`

Comment: Just use `re.sub(r'#.*', '#', text)` or  `re.sub(r'#\w.*', '#', text)`

Comment: `re.sub` with `(?<=#).*`

Comment: So, did anything work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
re.findall(r'^.*?(?:$|#)', text, re.M)
```

to match all of the substrings you want to keep and

```
re.findall(r'(?<=#).*$', text, re.M)
```

to match all of the substrings you want to reject.

Both use the `MULTILINE` flag and end-of-line `$` or `#` characters as boundaries.

Use caution when there are multiple `#`s in a line.